# MySQL: Can't access the temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have written this MySQL Stored procedure (Complete procedure at the end of question) and it's giving me error at the following statements:

```
UPDATE TrialBalTbl
    SET totalCred = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1CredSUM) FROM TrialBalTbl),
         totalDeb = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1DebSUM) FROM TrialBalTbl);
```

The error was:

> Can't reopen table

(`TrialBalTbl` is a temporary table) I searched over it and found [that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)

> You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query

So I thought to use alias `tbal` for the temporary table `TrialBalTbl` to achieve the effect and came up with this:

```
UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal
SET totalCred = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1CredSUM) FROM tbal),
        totalDeb = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1DebSUM) FROM tbal);
```

Now unfortunately, this doesn't work either. It says

> Table 'digitalmanager.tbal' doesn't exist

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with it? And how may I get this to work? Here is my complete stored procedure, which works until this `UPDATE` statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Trial_Balance`(IN startDate Varchar(200), IN endDate Varchar(200))
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS digitalmanager.TrialBalTbl;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TrialBalTbl (
    CTR INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PARTY_ID VARCHAR(100),
    ACCOUNT_ID VARCHAR(100),
    PARTY_NAME VARCHAR(500),
    DEBIT DECIMAL(19,2),
    CREDIT DECIMAL(19,2),
    L1  VARCHAR(200),
    L1NAME VARCHAR(1000),
    L2 VARCHAR(200),
    L2NAME VARCHAR(1000),
    L3 VARCHAR(200),
    L3NAME VARCHAR(1000),
    L1DebSUM decimal(19,2),
    L1CredSUM decimal(19,2),
    L2DebSUM decimal(19,2),
    L2CredSUM decimal(19,2),
    L3DebSUM decimal(19,2),
    L3CredSUM decimal(19,2),
    totalCred decimal(19,2),
    totalDeb decimal(19,2)
);

INSERT INTO TrialBalTbl
SELECT  
    null, 
    P.PARTY_ID, 
    P.ACCOUNT_ID,
    P.NAME,
    SUM(L.DEBIT)-SUM(L.CREDIT),
    0, 
    l1.L1,
    l1.`name` AS 'L1NAME',
    l2.L2, 
    l2.`name` AS 'L2NAME',
    l3.L3,
    l3.`name` AS 'L3NAME',
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
FROM 
    PLEDGER AS L INNER JOIN PARTY AS P ON L.party_id = p.party_id
    INNER JOIN level3 AS l3 ON l3.l3 = p.level3
    INNER JOIN level2 AS l2 ON l2.l2 = l3.l2
    INNER JOIN level1 AS l1 ON l1.l1 = l2.l1
WHERE 
    DATE(L.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
GROUP BY 
    l1.L1, l2.L2, l3.L3, P.PARTY_ID,P.NAME 
HAVING IFNULL(SUM(L.DEBIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(L.CREDIT),0) >0 
order by 
    P.ACCOUNT_ID ASC;

INSERT INTO TrialBalTbl
SELECT  
    null, 
    P.PARTY_ID, 
    P.ACCOUNT_ID,
    P.NAME,
    0,
    SUM(L.CREDIT)-SUM(L.DEBIT), 
    l1.L1, 
    L1.NAME AS 'L1NAME',
    l2.L2, 
    L2.NAME AS 'L2NAME',
    l3.L3,
    L3.NAME AS 'L3NAME',
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
FROM 
    PLEDGER AS L INNER JOIN PARTY AS P ON L.party_id = p.party_id
    INNER JOIN level3 AS l3 ON l3.l3 = p.level3
    INNER JOIN level2 AS l2 ON l2.l2 = l3.l2
    INNER JOIN level1 AS l1 ON l1.l1 = l2.l1
WHERE  
    DATE(L.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
GROUP BY  
    l1.L1, l2.L2, l3.L3, P.PARTY_ID,P.NAME HAVING IFNULL(SUM(L.CREDIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(L.DEBIT),0) > 0 
ORDER BY 
    P.ACCOUNT_ID ASC;

-- Update the whole level's credit and debit sums

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L1DebSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)-SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) 
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0) > 0
);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L1CredSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) -SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0) > 0
);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L2DebSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)-SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) 
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND level2.l2 = tbal.l2 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1, level2.L2
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0) > 0
);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L2CredSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) -SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND level2.l2 = tbal.l2 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1, level2.L2
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0) > 0
);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L3DebSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)-SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) 
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND level2.l2 = tbal.l2 AND level3.l3 = tbal.l3 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1, level2.L2, level3.L3
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0) > 0
);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl as tbal 
SET L3CredSUM = (
        SELECT SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT) -SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT)
        FROM 
            PLEDGER INNER JOIN PARTY ON PLEDGER.PARTY_ID = PARTY.PARTY_ID 
                    INNER JOIN Level3 ON level3.l3 = Party.level3 
                    INNER JOIN Level2 ON Level3.l2 = level2.l2 
                    INNER JOIN Level1 on Level1.l1 = level2.l1
        WHERE 
            level1.l1 = tbal.l1 AND level2.l2 = tbal.l2 AND level3.l3 = tbal.l3 AND DATE(PLEDGER.VRDATE) BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
        GROUP BY  
            level1.L1, level2.L2, level3.L3
        HAVING 
            IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.CREDIT),0)-IFNULL(SUM(PLEDGER.DEBIT),0) > 0
);
    -- PROBLEM here.
UPDATE TrialBalTbl
SET totalCred = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1CredSUM) FROM TrialBalTbl),
     totalDeb = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1DebSUM) FROM TrialBalTbl);

SELECT * FROM TrialBalTbl ORDER BY ACCOUNT_ID;

END
```

Comment: @Malimovka huh. There must be some way to achieve that.. I **used** the same way to update this temporary table above and it worked but isn't working on the said statement..

Comment: I think it may be to do with the grouping (using `DISTINCT` within the `SUM`).

Comment: There is no way to workaround that limitation (apart from upgrading to a DBMS that doesn't impose limits like that) - and even if you could use the temp table twice you are not allowed to use the table you are updating in a sub-select if I'm not mistaken

Comment: It's only a limitation on temp tables.  It works as expected on normal tables.

Comment: @AeroX: I'm not referring to the fact that the table is used twice, I'm referring to the fact that the table that is updated is used in a sub-select.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes sorry that's correct you can't do it the way the OP tried but you can do it in a single `UPDATE` without variables if you use a sub-query on a normal table [SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c08bf/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this by using a variable.

Declare two variables at the beginning of your procedure:

```
DECLARE @CredSUM decimal(19,2);
DECLARE @DebSUM  decimal(19,2);
```

Then set them and update the temp table using them:

```
SET @CredSUM = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1CredSUM) FROM TrialBalTbl);
SET @DebSUM  = (SELECT SUM(DISTINCT L1DebSUM ) FROM TrialBalTbl);

UPDATE TrialBalTbl SET
  totalCred = @CredSUM,
  totalDeb  = @DebSUM
;
```

Comment: It works but you haven't used the right syntax for variable declaration, I think... As variables in MySQL don't have `@` at the beginning, user defined variables do have `@` at the begining but to assign value to them, you have to use `:=` Isn't it?

Comment: To be honest I'm not 100% sure of the correct syntax as I've been working solely in MS-SQL for a few years now.  I tested this on SQL Fiddle before posting. Heres the [SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b14c16/1/0).

Comment: I've just looked it up again and it's `:=` to assign as part of a `SELECT` and just `=` as part of a `SET`.